# Get output from netcat and send response

Tags: python, bash

```
~$ nc 0.0.0.0 11111
==========
echo me: 20744467
==========
20744467
Correct!

==========
echo me: 78587225
==========
78587225
Correct!

==========
echo me: 98051617
==========
...
```

etc

I tried `nc 0.0.0.0 11111 > output.txt` and it seems like the output can be sent to `output.txt` but I got no idea how to send response back automatically by script (see code block above).

Edit:

I tried python script:

```
import socket, sys

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((ip, port))

while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data: sys.exit(0)
        print("server output:\n" + data) #debug
        input = ""
        for elem in data:
                if elem.isnumeric():
                        input = input + elem
        print("input = " + input)
        sock.send(input.encode())
```

It will stuck at the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

try redirect and tee

```
nc 0.0.0.0 11111 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -N

```
for R in 20744467 78587225 98051617 ; do printf '%s\n' "${R}" ; done | nc -N 0.0.0.0 11111 > output.txt
```

Comment: I'm sorry for ambiguity, but those numbers are random. So I think I need to read the output, get the number after `echo` and send it back.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked.